# Max time limits in each stage for a Area51 site proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

It is stated in Area51 FAQ that:

1. A site goes through several phases
   before it launches to the public.
2. If the site loses focus or momentum
   during this process, it will be
   closed down and the proposal
   reevaluated… hopefully to a more
   successful launch at a future date.

But it is not clear what will be considered `losing focus or momentum`. Specifically, is there a defined time limit a proposal can stay in each of the four stages before it is closed down?

Comment: It has been repeatedly stated that there is simply not enough data available yet to set hard rules for certain things. Then of course there is the question of wether focus & momentum *can* be reliably expressed with fixed rules.

Comment: Thank you Georg, but why didn't you put that as an answer, after all it explains there are no rules set yet and why. Also, could you include a few references of where it has been (repeatedly) stated there is not enough data for setting of such rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more important question is *not likely to ever gain* Vs. *losing*.

Losing, in the context of *interest*, implies a proposal that generated some interest and stopped gaining interest for whatever reason.

Then, there are proposals that simply gain no interest at all.

Analytically, they really are two different things, especially in the context of what Area 51 could be doing differently and how much time should be afforded to either case.

Comment: `Should be`? So indeed it is not decided yet? And you are right, now that I think about it I see that I was more worried about `not gaining` and I wanted to know how long the people who watch over the proposals will wait before they decide they should kill the proposal.